# Check if Folder exists in simplekml - python

Tags: python, directory, containers, kml, simplekml

This should be extremely easy but I've now been at it an hour with no end in site. I'm using the simplekml module in python and I want to create a folder if one doesn't exists. I can't find anyway to check if a folder exists already without creating a for loop. I would think the below would work but of course it doesn't.

```
    kml = simplekml.Kml()
    testfold = kml.newfolder(name = 'testfolder')
    testfold2 = kml.newfolder(name = 'testfolder2')

    if 'testfolder' in kml.containers: 
        print True
```

The only thing that seems to return the fold names is:

```
for x in kml.containers:
    print x.name
```

But of course I would prefer not to iterate through every container in the kml file looking for a folder before then writing it if it isn't found. Please tell me there's a better way?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because, kml.containers holds the list of objects of class simplekml.featgeom.Folder and `name` is an attribute of that class!

So when you check `if 'testfolder' in kml.containers` it returns `false`! You have to fetch the values in the name attribute of that container and then check if `testfolder`

```
>>> [each for each in kml.containers]
[<simplekml.featgeom.Folder object at 0x2ac156d8e910>, <simplekml.featgeom.Folder object at 0x2ac156d8e890>]
>>> [x.name for x in kml.containers]
['testfolder', 'testfolder2']
>>> True if 'testfolder' in [x.name for x in kml.containers] else False
True
```

Comment: Thanks Keerthana. One question, will this loop through all "points" as well? In other words, if every time I'm adding a point I have to loop through all points and folders to look for a folder, this could get very slow for adding a large number of points.

Comment: I get it. Definitely there will be an overhead if you loop through the kml.containers every time. I suggest to add the points to a list, and as and when you add a new point, append to that list. So while comparing you can make use of the updated list!